# How to have an /etc/xdg/autostart/app.desktop service wait for a (systemd) service?

Tags: systemd, init-script, sysvinit, autologin, xdg

TLDR:

How to have an `/etc/xdg/autostart/app.desktop` service wait for a systemd service?

Long:

I have an app started by `/etc/xdg/autostart/app.desktop` that requires a systemd service to be started first.

I would like to avoid some sleep/wait/custom code if there is an existing tool for such purposes.

Is there some kind of `wait_for_service_to_be_running <service-name>` (systemd) command line tool?

Answer (score -1):

Create `yourservice.service` file, place it into `/etc/systemd/system/` and run `systemctl start yourservice` by your .desktop file.

```
[Unit]
Requires=somesystemd.service
After=somesystemd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/yourservice
```

Or you can replace `app.desktop` with systemd configuration. Create `replacement.service` as above with additional section:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run it with `systemctl enable replacement.service`.

[Systemd service - what is `multi-user.target`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404667/systemd-service-what-is-multi-user-target) can give more details.

Comment: /etc/xdg/autostart/ is for users when the desktop environment starts. /etc/systemd/system/ is for root.

Comment: @adrelanos `systemd` doesn't look into `/etc/xdg/autostart` - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#

Comment: I am aware of that. My question remains the same.

Comment: I see. You don't want to rewrite desktop shortcut as a `systemd` service.